# PHP and mysqli working but cause a 'Aborted connection' warning

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a very simple test php:

```
<?php
require("conf.php");

$connection = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);
mysqli_set_charset($connection,"utf8");

$query = "CALL `DB1`.`list_cities`();";
$result = $connection->query($query); 
$connection->close();
?>
```

When I run it, my MySQL server return this warning:

> [Warning] Aborted connection to db: 'DB1' user: 'user1' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)

But if I replace the '$query = CALL...' and use the actual `SELECT` instead of calling a stored procedure, there is no warning.

I tried to increase MySQL (Mariadb 10.5.18) max_allowed_packet to 1GB, increase the number of connections but it doesn't go away.

The code is working fine, but mysql is flooding my log with these warnings.

Comment: How about if you fetch the remaining result instead of killing off the connection? Does that get rid of the warning?

Comment: No. The original php have the fetch_assoc and everything else. I simplified the most possible my php to debug and the warning continues. Even if I try another S.P. . I’m beginning to think this is a sql problem

Comment: Are you saying that `next_result()` doesn't work?